# Powershell - Get-ChildItem wildcard

Tags: powershell

Get-ChildItem `filename*.log.*` fetches `filename*.log` as well. How can I get only the log files ending with dot extension  `filename*.log.*` so I can delete them? I want to use Remove-Item but decided to check using get-childItem.

Here is the files.

```
Server1234.log
Server1234.log.1
Server1234.log.2
Server1234.log.3
Server1234.log.4
```

Get-ChildItem `filename*.log.*`  shows all of the above. I don't want `Server1234.log` in the output.

Comment: `Server*.log.*` won't fetch `Server1234.log`

Comment: Its weird. I just double checked and its not fetching. But a while ago I saw it happen where Server1234.log was displayed. Anyway I'm glad it is working as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the filter

```
Get-ChildItem filename*.log.?*
```

The question mark states that at least one character has to be there...

Comment: The dot after the log already omits the Server1234.log output, I think the example is not correctly described by John...

Answer (score 3):

Your filter should work. I have created 3 files:

```
New-Item 'Server1234.log' -ItemType File
New-Item 'Server1234.log.1' -ItemType File
New-Item 'Server1234.log.2' -ItemType File
```

And here is the **output** of `Get-ChildItem Server1234*.log.*`

```
PS D:\> Get-ChildItem Server1234*.log.*

    Directory: D:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                       
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                       
-a----       13/05/2020     10:51              0 Server1234.log.1                                                                                                           
-a----       13/05/2020     10:51              0 Server1234.log.2
```

**Note:** The filter parameter of the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet *doesn't use regex!* If you want to use regex you can do this within the `Where-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'Server123.*log\.+' }
```